# Skipping clean build using xctool

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild, xctool

Is there a way to skip the clean build process using xctool? I'm usually building an xcode project via some automation script and I'm not making any changes to the xcode project itself. I'm just testing automation scripts changes and it would be helpful to avoid doing the clean build every single time.

Comment: `xctool` doesn't do a clean build by default. How are you calling it? Why do you think it's doing a clean build?

Comment: ~/xctool/xctool.sh ARCHS=i386 -sdk iphonesimulator -workspace Test.xcworkspace -scheme Test build CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR="/home/test/build"

Comment: And why do you think it's doing a clean build that it doesn't need to do (i.e. one that building the Test scheme in the Test workspace in Xcode wouldn't have done)? xctool doesn't by default.

Comment: Found the issue. There was a condition I missed in the script that was causing a clean build to be passed in. I can't go in to detail but I was able to add parameters to skip the clean build. Thanks for helping out.